# High charts – how to show axis as time

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

May I ask for some help display the x axis of a highchart with time based labels. The charts spans 30 hours and my json has 690 elements in the data part. My json is formatted like this …

```
[{
    "name": "seriesName",
    "data": [
        0.04,
        0.04,
        0.07,
        0.44,
        0.12,
        0,
        0.80,
        -0.02
    ]
}]
```

In essence, every 23rd element marks the start of a new hour and the charts starts at 18:00 the previous day, up until 23:59 today.

I have put together a fiddle to help show the issues I’m having. I’m sorry, for some reason I am just not getting the relationship between xAxis - tickInterval, plotOptions – series - pointInterval and pointStart.

http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyRS/24m1b19b/1/

Should my json array have another element that represents the time for each value point ? I'd like to show a tick that represents each new hours from 18:00 the previous day, till midnight today.

Just is case it’s important, I should also mention that the fiddle is only a representation of the chart as I collect the data from a mySQL db after a button click. This I how I build the chart …

```
jQuery("document").ready(function() {
    var options = {
            chart: { … },
            xAxis: { … },
            yAxis: { … },
            plotOptions: { … },
            series: [{}]
    }; // var options

    loadSeries();   
    function loadSeries(){
        $.post("//somePath/test.php", data, function(json) {
            options.series[0] = json[0];
            options.series[1] = json[1];
            options.series[2] = json[2];
            options.series[3] = json[3];

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

            chart.series[0].options.animation = false;
            chart.series[0].options.lineWidth = 1;
            chart.series[0].update(chart.series[0].options);

            chart.series[1].options.animation = false;
            chart.series[1].options.lineWidth = 1;
            chart.series[1].update(chart.series[1].options);
        }, "json"); // $.post
    } // loadSeries

    $('#btn').click(function() {
        loadSeries();
    });
}); // ready
```

Thank you for taking the time to read the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify time using array of numbers, the first index represents time and the second represents the value.

```
  data: [
                [Date.UTC(2000,  9, 27), 0   ],
                [Date.UTC(2000, 10, 10), 0.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(2000, 10, 18), 0.7 ],
                [Date.UTC(2000, 11,  2), 0.8 ],
                [Date.UTC(2000, 11,  9), 0.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(2000, 11, 16), 0.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(2000, 11, 28), 0.67],
                [Date.UTC(2001,  1,  1), 0.81],
                [Date.UTC(2001,  1,  8), 0.78],
                [Date.UTC(2001,  1, 12), 0.98]

            ]
```

See example here : http://jsfiddle.net/0v6LphLd/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'll rebuild my json array the way you have described.